# exponentialfunction poofs with generating functions

Tags: combinatorics, exponential-function

I have two things to proof.

$(e^{ax})^{-1}=e^{-ax}$ and
$(e^{ax})^{m}=e^{(ma)x}$

I know the power series of $e^x$ and $e^{ax}$ and that $e^{ax}e^{bx}=e^{(a+b)x}$

I tried it forward and backward:
$(e^{ax})^{-1}=(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}(ax)^n)^{-1}
= \frac{1}{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}(ax)^n}$

and i dont know how to continue. I know that i want this
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}(-ax)^n$ or

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}(ax)^n$

I think if i know how to solve the first problem, i know how to solve the secound one. They look similar.

Comment: I think for the first one, you should show $e^{ax} e^{-ax}=1$ by multiplying the two power series.

Comment: Thank you.... it seems to work